# Create a subprocess in a new shell that can be killed at any point

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, unix, subprocess

I want to run a terminal command in a separate shell, but I also want to be able to kill/terminate it at any time. I've read some answers here, and they say to do something like `process = subprocess.Popen(args=['gnome-terminal', '--command=%s' % cmd])`. The problem with this is, calling `process.kill()` or `process.terminate()` after the new shell has been opened does nothing. I want to be able to call a function and kill or terminate the new shell process.

Comment: Why did you just delete your existing question and then ask the same question with minor changes?

Comment: @abarnert It's not a minor change. I realised that my question was stupid, and that there's a completely different issue at hand. I felt that it wouldn't be ok to just completely re-write the question and decided to make a new one. I'm sorry if that was the wrong thing to do, however.

Comment: The real question is why you want to do this. To run a terminal command, you don't need to run it in `gnome-terminal`. You only do that if you specifically want to display the output in `gnome-terminal`, and I'm not sure why you'd want to do that (why not just, e.g., pipe it to… whatever replaced `gtkless` back in the 2.0 era?).

Comment: The reason is, I want to run a command, and then at some point terminate it, but I don't know when. I have a function that tells me whether it should be terminated or not, and I'm calling it at regular intervals to check and stop the command if need be.

Comment: Sure, but why do you want to run the command *in gnome-terminal*?

Comment: No reason, it's just that the answer that I found here said to do so. Is there a better way? I've tried setting `shell=True` to no avail.

Comment: If you just want to run a program, just run the program. Only if you need the shell should you add `shell=True`. Only if you need a terminal window to run the shell to run the command, so it can display the output and let the user interact with it like a normal terminal, should you run a terminal.

Comment: Well, here's the problem. I start running the program, and until it stops I can't do anything else: the code is synchronous. But I want to stop it at some point, not by manually interrupting but with python. I need to have checking code (do we stop the program now? how about now? what about *now*?) running alongside the command. I thought that the best way to do that is to run in separate terminals. Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you want something like a pidfile?

Answer (score -1):

The [`gnome-terminal`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-gnome-terminal/) command is not actually the terminal program; it's a launcher that talks to a factory and asks it to reuse an existing terminal program to open a new window or tab, or to create a new terminal program if necessary.

So, killing this launcher doesn't make any sense. And, even if it would tell you the PID of the actual terminal process, you wouldn't want to kill that, because it could kill a bunch of other terminal sessions.

You can use the `--disable-factory` flag to avoid this behavior:

> Do not register with the activation name server, do not re-use an active terminal.

For more information on the details of `gnome-terminal`, you probably want to search or ask somewhere else (probably [Super User](https://superuser.com/), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), or [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)), but this should be all you need for your problem.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I though: `gnome-terminal` isn't the actual process that  I want to kill. Would using this flag still open a new terminal though?

Comment: @Bluefire Using this flag guarantees a new terminal, independent from any existing terminals.